# How costly is getString(android.R.string.resource_id)?

Tags: android, string, performance

I have different locales and strings that count to 600-800. I want to know if I can reduce the string retrieval across my android app lower than `getString(android.R.string.resource_id)`. Are there any efficient implementations? I know `findViewById()` is costly, but I don't know if this is costly.

Comment: What do you mean by `android.R.string.resource_id`? You mean using `getString(int)`?

Comment: are you really facing performance issues with string resource retrieval? I don't think the implied anti-pattern needed to change the way you load strings is worth it